# Java RegEx match string containing non-ASCII that exceeds given length

Tags: java, regex

How do I determine if the string contains non-ASCII AND exceeds 5 characters using RegEx?

I tried this pattern: `(?=\P{ASCII})(?=^.{6,}$)`
I thought `(?=)` means (?=must be this)(?=and this too).

Given this input: `1巻345`
I'm expecting matcher `find()` to return false.

Given this input: `1巻34567`
I'm expecting matcher `find()` to return true.

But it always returns false on both inputs.

Please also explain why my given pattern doesn't work.

**UPDATE:**
I figured the right pattern: `(\P{ASCII})(.{6,})`

Now I only need to know why `(?=)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
^(?=.*\P{ASCII}).{6,}$
```

So let's explain it:

```
^                       # Begin of string
    (?=                 # Take a look and make sure if there is
        .*              # Anything zero or more times (greedy)
        \P{ASCII}       # A non-ascii character
    )                   # End of lookahead
    .{6,}               # Match any character 6 or more times
$                       # End of string
```

Let's analyse why your pattern fails `(?=\P{ASCII})(?=^.{6,}$)`:

1. `(?=\P{ASCII})` you're first telling the regex engine to check if there is a non-ascii character.
2. `(?=^.{6,}$)` then you're telling the regex engine to check if it's the beginning of string with `^` in the lookahead, and then checking if there is 6 or more characters.

Now look at your input, you've got `1巻34567`. And you're telling the regex engine if the **first** character is non-ascii, which is **false** since the first character is `1`. Try `巻345671` as input and it should output **true**.

Note that `.` doesn't match newline. So you might want to set the `s` modifier by using `(?s)`:
`(?s)^(?=.*\P{ASCII}).{6,}$`.

Comment: If I only use `(?=\P{ASCII})` then it returns **true** but if I use both `(?=\P{ASCII})(?=^.{6,}$)` then it returns **false** care to explain why?

Comment: I think your statement maybe incorrect. -> "And you're telling the regex engine if the first character is non-ascii, which is false since the first character is 1. Try 巻345671 as input and it should output true." Because `(?=\P{ASCII})` returns true as long as the string contains non-ASCII regardless of where it is located. I'm not sure if I got your point right.

Comment: @supertonsky If you only use `(?=\P{ASCII})`, then you're not asserting it to be at the beginning of string since there is no `^`. Try to use `(?=^\P{ASCII})` or `(?=\P{ASCII})(?=^)`, it should return **false**.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to see your point. You mean to say `(?=^)` affects how `(?=\P{ASCII})` will be applied against the string to find a match? I thought they are totally independent as sort of: 1) Check if there's non-Asian chars 2) check if length is within specified range **regardless** or **independent** of the previous condition. Or was that assumption wrong?

Comment: @supertonsky Could you join the [regex chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex) ? It's quite long to explain this in details. Also I'm quite busy at the moment.